# Help with transfering items to rig

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, weight-painting

This may have been answered in another post, is so simply direct me to that post. (I had a pretty hard time searching for it)

Here's my problem- I've been trying to transfer (or move, not yet any good with terminology) the shoes I've modeled for my character to the rig so that when I move his foot, the shoes will move with it. But every time I do, the shoes become off set from where I modeled them. (pics will be posted for better example) Does anyone know why this is happening?? Its probably a simple issue I'm just missing.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean move/transfer? are you adding the shoes to the rig?
If you are it may be the case that your rig isn't in resting pose, as such when you add the shoes they are being transformed by the bones rotation, effectively causing a double transform, as they are being rotated once by you and once more by the bones.

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to add the shoes to the rig. Sorry I wasn't clear. Had a hard time trying to word the question. I'm pretty sure I have the rig in resting mode but I will double check. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Thank you so much @Firewill !! Turns out you were right!! I just knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did't add the Armature Modifier to the shoes. You need the armature to deform the shoes, using same vertex group names you used for feet.

Comment: I did that, and got the same result

Answer (score 1):

In case it gets by passed, @Firewill helped me to solve the issue I was having. I was trying to add the shoes to the rig, but the objects would always end up off set. @Firewill discovered that my rig was not in resting pose. Simple solution. I clicked the armature and went into pose mode. From there I hit ALT-R to put the rig in resting pose. I then went into object mode and clicked on the shoes object and Shift-clicked the armature. Next I hit Ctrl-P > with automatic weights and boom goes the dynamite. All fixed
 Thanks again @Firewill.